# Why do I keep getting a error? - Pinscript Coding Error

Tags: pine-script

I am getting multiple errors when using this code, this is a code I have used from someone else & is part of a bigger script but i have no errors elsewhere just when I get to this part... Can anybody pointout, where I have made mistakes in writing this code?

I have attached a picture of the issue...

[image]

Comment: Please post the actual code, not the image.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess, I'd say that the line that starts:

```
if ((bar_index
```

Has one too many opening parenthesis.

Try:

```
if (bar_index
```

Comment: Thanks, thats worked. Now I am getting this error for line 40: line 40: Mismatched input 'clear0rder' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'.